# What are the effects of the real image formed by the hologram?

Tags: optics, hologram

Interference effects of hologram film produces a virtual image at the position of the original object and a real image an equal distance away.

[image]

Would the real image distort the virtual image to an audience who is viewing the virtual image in the direction of the real image? If so, are there any means to reduce the impact?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the hologram was made using a reference beam as you have indicated, and an object beam corresponding to your dotted lines, an observer at the location of the eye will not see the real image that forms at the bottom right.  That real image will not affect the virtual image at all.

Note that some kinds of holograms - specifically, volume holograms - reduce the real image to almost zero.  And, if the reference beam angle is strongly tilted when the hologram is made and reconstructed, there may be no real image formed at all.